# Cucumber and Seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, seed

can we load seed data when start cucumber?
Please support me a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Factory Girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to in your cucumber tests to setup your 'stuff'

```
Background:
  A car exists

Scenario: I drive a car
  Given I am in a car
  And I have keys in the ignition
  When I turn the keys
  ...
```

Then you'll create the car in your step definitions, with something like

```
@car = Factory.create(:car)
```

Comment: Don't you need the step keyword? e.g. Given A car exists

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this approach:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/fixtures

I'm not opening the fixtures vs factories debate, of course, just saying that I've yet to see a case where files of data (seed, or otherwise) cease to be useful.

Once yaml fixtures are defined, they can be instantiated procedurally via `Fixtures.create_fixtures` per above, or set up as rake tasks.

They're just plain files, not code intended to have side effects - I have more confidence letting non-technical people add their data to fixtures files (esp. CSV).